# Magnifier coming in Nexus on touch input

Tags: javascript

I am working on a asset which used html,css and javascript. when i run it on nexus then a magnifier coming which is actually magnifying the touched area for user input. Is there any way to disable it using js,jquery.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your css

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-khtml-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: it doesn't conpletely disable the magnifier. still coming on clicking in input field

Comment: it doesn't conpletely disable the magnifier. still coming may be due to small size of input. it doesnt come on enlarging the input.